# Android can't load local libcrypto unsatisfied link error

Tags: android, java-native-interface, openssl, shared-libraries, android-ndk

I need to run a newer version of openssl in my app than the one that comes in the OS. I was able to patch and android source to compile a newer version and then extract the shared library to use in my app.

I was then able to compile and link my native code that requires a function only in newer versions of openssl against my new shared library (the patch to a newer openssl worked).

I was also able to create a few jni functions that work as expected but as soon as I added in the function that is only in the newer openssl shared library local to the app I get an unsatisfied link error.

My assumption is that the system version of libcrypto and libssl are overriding my local versions in /libs/armeabi/libcrypto.so and /libs/armeabi/libssl.so   .... how to I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system already ships with a library known as `libcrypto`, and that will be picked before your library will. The easiest solution is to give your library a different name, and use that in your `System.loadLibrary(...)` call.

**Update**

As you pointed out, you will need to rebuild the library with the new name, in stead of just renaming the file.

Comment: I tried changing the filename of libcrypto.so to something else but that didn't work. Does filename not matter and I have to change it in the openssl build?

Comment: True, you will need to rebuild the library with this new name. I updated the answer based on your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes JNI is picking up the system versions. It didn't use your patched versions at all. On standalone JVM you would say `-Djava.library.path=/libs/armeabi` or modify environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. On Android i guess you can either look up the system property **java.library.path** and put your libs in some known place (but before the folder where the system versions are) or actually modify the property - prepend the path to your local versions. I do have some experience with Android but not specifically with NDK.