# Undefined reference to 'SSL_new' building for Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, ndk-build

When I try to build my android app with native code that relay on libssl.so and libcrypto.so I get the "undefined reference to SSL_new" linkage error. 
What I'm doing wrong in my android.mk and application.mk?

Both mk files reside at \home\project_root\app\src\main\jni.
Here is android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := myWebCrawler
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libssl.so ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.so

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := utils/error_codes.c utils/list.c  yetAdditionalSources.c    

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My application.mk contains a single line:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

In my project folder I have the fallowing sub folders:
\home\project_root\app\src\main\libs\armeabi,
\home\project_root\app\src\main\libs\armeabi-v7a,
\home\project_root\app\src\main\libs\arm64-v8a,
\home\project_root\app\src\main\libs\mips64

each of them have a copy of libssl.so and libcrypto.so.
There are also copies at paths `$(NDK_ROOT\platforms\android-21\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\usr\lib)`
for all the archtures. (x86, mips, arm...)

What I'm doing wrong? why ndk build does not find the .so files?

Also, when I call ndk-build from terminal I get an error regarding the arm architecture
recipe for target '/home/WebCrawler/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi/libWebCrawler.so' failed

while when clicking the build button in android studio it refers to mips
`make: *** [/home/WebCrawler/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libWebCrawler.so] Error 1` even though Application.mk dose not mention mips in the instruction `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a`

If you need more info in order to help me fike the mk's please do ask for it.

Comment: Also see [Undefined reference to 'DTLS_client_method'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18419123/608639). I despise Android's build system. It changes too many things and its poorly documented. You will likely waste hours on this issue.

Comment: Already spent over a week trying to understand the different variables in android.mk and building ssl for android from source...

Comment: So, the trick is to come up with a new module with renaming ssl?

Comment: *`../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libssl.so`* - yeah, this will get you in trouble. `zygote`, which is Android's `init`, will load a down level version of OpenSSL. Your version of OpenSSL will never load because Android's version is loaded. You should do the wrapper shared object thing. Also see [Android | Wrapper_Shared_Objects](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Wrapper_Shared_Objects) on the OpenSSL wiki.