# How to deploy native library separately on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, apk

I am struggling with slow packaging and deployment issue on my project. It takes about 10 seconds for a native library per architecture to be packaged.

I want to speed up my build & deployment cycle separating the native library from the package as the changes for the native library does not happen very often.

My idea is to deploy the native library to the device separately and create .apk without the lib for less time consumption.

Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted, you can push the library into `/system/lib` (going through `adb remount`). Now, the Java call `System.loadLibrary("mynative")` will transparently load `/system/lib/libmynative.so` instead of `/data/app-lib/com.my.app/libmynative.so` (*catch: it will do so even if the file `/data/app-lib/com.my.app/libmynative.so` exists, therefore we must choose the names of the native libraries with care, so that they do no get "hidden" by a system lib, including the most esoteric devices, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004872/192373*).

On the other hand, you can push the library elsewhere, and - until the app stabilizes - replace `System.loadLibrary("mynative")` with `System.load("/data/local/tmp/libmynative.so")` or whatever path you prefer.